# Using nuint with asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, nunit

I have an existing asp.net webforms application with all its business logic and DAL in the app_code folder.

What is the best way to structure tests with nunit ? Add a separate test project to the solution or do I have to put the tests in the app_Code folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Ayende's suggestion in the blog post below. I would create a separate project for tests but I would try to never add another project after that point simply folders.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/02/22/The-two-project-solution.aspx

- MyApp
        o /Model
        o /Web
        o /Services
        o /Infrastructure

  - MyApp.Tests

You should not have to put your tests in the app_code folder.